# Fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer in custom navigationcontroller

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm creating a custom navigation controller. I have something like this:

```
public class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    // MARK: - Life Cycle

    override init(rootViewController: UIViewController) {
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)

        delegate = self
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        delegate = self
    }
}
```

I wanted to test this out so I created a CustomNavigationController like this:

```
CustomNavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
```

When I run the app I get this:

```
fatal error: use of unimplemented initializer 'init(nibName:bundle:)' for class 'TestApp.CustomNavigationController'
```

I don't see the problem, can anyone help me out?

Comment: what is `delegate = self`  ? after just deleting that I could run your code without issue

Comment: That's the UINavigationControllerDelegate.

Comment: This is fixed in iOS 13 - the same code does not result in a fatalError

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`UINavigationController`'s implementation of `init(rootViewController:)` probably calls `self.init(nibName:bundle:)` which you haven't implemented so it throws the error.

You should override `init(nibName:bundle)` in addition to the initializers you already override.  `init(nibName:bundle:)` is a designated initializer while `init(rootViewController:)` is a convenience initializer.

Comment: init(rootViewController:) cannot be a convenience initializer. As stated in the initializer delegation rules (listed in @Jack's answer below), a designated initializer can only call up to another designated initializer. It should be a compiler error if you attempt to call a superclass convenience initializer from a designated subclass initializer.

Comment: Thanks.. Helps me a lot in my keyboard extension :)

Comment: This crash is suddenly appeared for iOS12 users. Although empty initialiser doesn't make any sense, it fixes that crash.

Answer (score 34):

While using custom navigation controller, we need to use `override init`property of `NavigationController`
as-

```
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }
    override init(rootViewController: UIViewController) {
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    }
    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

}
```

& in `Appdelegate` class use -

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let vc = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
        let navi =  CustomNavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        window?.backgroundColor = .white
        window?.rootViewController = navi
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}
```

As per Apple Document -
To simplify the relationships between designated and convenience initializers, Swift applies the following three rules for delegation calls between initializers:

> Rule 1 A designated initializer must call a designated initializer
>   from its immediate superclass.
>
> Rule 2 A convenience initializer must call another initializer from
>   the same class.
>
> Rule 3 A convenience initializer must ultimately call a designated
>   initializer.
>
> A simple way to remember this is:-

[image]

Answer (score 13):

I had this issue happen to users on iOS 12.4, so to do a workaround in my custom initializer I did something like this:

```
init(rootViewController: UIViewController, numberOfPages: Int) {
    self.numberOfPages = numberOfPages
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    } else {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.viewControllers = [rootViewController]
    }
}
```

I basically initialize my class differently for every iOS version below 13. This does seem like the shortest solution.

Comment: This solution works well if your subclass has properties needs to be initialized before calling `super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)`